# sed unterminated `s' command when attaching code to a block

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

This is the file I would like to change. I would like to add an entry under `servers {`.

```
eap-radius {

    # Section to specify multiple RADIUS servers.
    servers {

    }
}
```

This is what I have tried

```
sed -i '/servers {/a\
server-a {
            accounting = yes
            secret = 123456
            address = 127.0.0.1
            auth_port = 1812
            acct_port = 1813
}
' /etc/strongswan.d/charon/eap-radius.conf
```

> sed: -e expression #1, char 81: unterminated `s' command

Comment: suggestion: save the text in a file and use `r` command.. it will robust irrespective of what characters you have.. while `a` command will interpret backslash sequences and other things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape new-lines:

```
sed '/servers {/a\
        server-a {\
            accounting = yes\
            secret = 123456\
            address = 127.0.0.1\
            auth_port = 1812\
            acct_port = 1813\
        }
' ./test.txt
```

The results are (I also tabbed a bit `server-a` block):

```
eap-radius {

    # Section to specify multiple RADIUS servers.
    servers {
        server-a {
            accounting = yes
            secret = 123456
            address = 127.0.0.1
            auth_port = 1812
            acct_port = 1813
        }

    }
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, GNU bash version 4.3.11(1)-release